# Shall a Model class in CodeIgniter send back MySQL error messages as they are to the controller class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, crud

I'm writing a CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) model in the CI (CodeIgniter) framework.

I ask, as security and accordance to the MVC paradigm, shall my Model send the eventual MySQL error messages as they are to the controller when they happen, knowing that they can contain table or column names, or, I  shall "map" these errors inside the model and communicate with the controller with my proper feed-backs.

Comment: For development you could output as is for easier debugging, for production you better do what you are suggesting.

Comment: In production, models should communicate user friendly error messages to the controller and the controller to the end user. In development environment, you see the mysql error messages and cure them.

Comment: and as security measures?

Comment: something like this?
private function mysql_error_CI(){
   
   if (defined('DEVELEOPMENT'))
    return mysql_error();
   else
    return "Oops, database access error :(";
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

In production the user needs to see only basic error informations. Only in development you can display all errors to debug them. From my opinion there is no need to show users you table structure and rest ...

Comment: so when we talk about sending feed-backs to the controller, we are talking about development context, not an end-user one? right?

Comment: Yes. CI was $config['log_threshold'] = X; that you can use to for debug and if you want even more you can use something like :           $log = "you error message";  log_message('error', $log); and this will output the custom error to error logs ..

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to show the end user any error logs, or give them any suggestion to why the query failed.

A simple error message will suffice

```
$this->session->set_flashadata('error', 'An error occured, please contact an admin!');
```

---

```
class Model extends CI_Model
{
    /**
     *
     * @return mixed Object if query is true, false otherwise 
    **/
    public function method()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

        // conditional behavior
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
            return $query->result();

        // default behavior
        log_message('error', $this->db->_error_message());
        //might also be useful to email an admin to notify him
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->model = $this->load->model('Model');
    }

    public function method()
    {
        if(!$this->model->method()){
            $this->session
                 ->set_flashadata('error', 'An error occured, please contact an admin!');
        }
        else{
            $this->session
                 ->set_flashadata('success', 'Good job!');
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }

}
```